# Convert multiple columns to "Date" in a large list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, as.date

I'm working with a large dataset that is stored in a list. The list contains 450 dataframes. Every dataframe looks the same (same column names) but with different values:
Here is an example of one dataframe:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(1:10, .Label = c("01.01.2009 00:00:00", 
"01.01.2009 01:00:00", "01.01.2009 02:00:00", "01.01.2009 03:00:00", 
"01.01.2009 04:00:00", "01.01.2009 05:00:00", "01.01.2009 06:00:00", 
"01.01.2009 07:00:00", "01.01.2009 08:00:00", "01.01.2009 09:00:00"
), class = "factor"), SWC = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I wanna convert the column "Date" to Date with `as.Date()` for every single dataframe in the list. Because of that I created a for loop:

```
for (i in length(list.data.SM)) {

list.data.SM[[i]] <- as.Date(list.data.SM[[i]]$Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
}
```

Afterwards I wanted to subset data from the first dataframe in the list by:

```
subset2009 <- subset(list.data.SM[[1]], Date <= "2009-12-31 23:00:00")
```

The subset now returns "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" which I'm really confused about because there is no $ in the code. Furthermore I realized that after my for-loop the "list.data.SM" turned into a value and does not show up as Data in the Global Environment anymore.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Store `list.data.SM[[i]]$Date` instead of `list.data.SM[[i]]` in the for loop

Comment: You only provide one df but question is on lists.

Comment: @Clemsang I did and the loop did not produce an error. If I type `is.Date(list.data.SM[[1]]$Date)` it says "FALSE".

Comment: @Phil Your code shows `list.data.SM[[i]] <- as.Date(...`. What @Clemsang is saying is that you forgot the `$Date`. As it is, you're overwriting the entire list element with the date

Comment: This is also where your subset error comes from. Since you're trying to access the 'Date' column of `list[[i]]` when `list[[i]]` is now just a vector (hence "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors")

Comment: How you list look like? sample data is one dataframe

Comment: @RoB I understood that and changed it to

 
`for (i in length(list.data.SM)) {
  
  list.data.SM[[i]]$Date <- as.Date(list.data.SM[[i]]$Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")`
}

Then I checked if the column is now a "Date" by typing `is.Date(list.data.SM[[1]]$Date)` but it says FALSE, so obviously changing the loop did not fix it.

Comment: @nurandi I'm sorry, I'm new to R. How could I show you what my list looks like so you can reproduce what I did and what it looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to the problem was using `seq_along` in the for loop. So I wrote:

```
for (i in seq_along(list.data.SM)) {

  list.data.SM[[i]]$Date <- as.Date(list.data.SM[[i]]$Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
}
```